# Grails: getAll throwing no signature of method exception?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

According to the Grails literature

http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/getAll.html

I should be able to do this

```
 def biweeklyBatchRanges = BiweeklyBatchRange.getAll()
```

without getting this

```
    groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.myplang.donation.BiweeklyBatchRange.getAll() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: getAll(), getAt(java.lang.String), getId(), get(java.io.Serializable), getClass(), findAll()
```

Any ideas?  TIA!

Comment: Does `getAll([1, 2, 3])` work as expected?

Comment: You linked to the docs for 2.0.  Are you using Grails 2.0?  Or possibly an earlier version?

Comment: I have had the same issue, it seems kind of jumpy. Try using findAll.

Comment: I am using 2.0.3.  findAll did the trick.  Thanks marko!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never got an "answer" to this, except to use findAll. (Grails 2.0.3)